# Максимальный элемент в STL Vector C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector, stl

Я решаю проблему в которой в какой то момент нужно взять элемент с максимальным значением в векторе(или в отрезке вектора)
я нашел функцию max_element но оно работает медленно
мне нужно чтоб я указывал аргументы как в max_element 
там указывается так - `max_element(vectorname.begin(), vectorname.end())`

Comment: Ну тогда делайте свой тип и храните отдельно значение максимального элемента и обновляйте при вставке... В неотсортированном массиве лучше O(N) ничего не получится. Так что используйте какую-то другую структуру данных...

Comment: А вообще лучше задавать вопрос с общей проблемой - а то это может оказаться вопросом, какой рукой держать микроскоп, забивая гвозди, а не как забить гвоздь...